# Установка vsftpd на Debian

Tags: ftp, debian

Начитавшись статей в интернете, я установил этот vsftpd. Но он не работает. 
Сначала он выдавал "Ooops! Bad bool value on ..." на все значения в vsftpd.conf. Я уж думал, что там конфигурация другая. 
Пробовал менять на варианты YES, NO, TRUE, FALSE, 0, 1. 
Пробовал менять кодировку на UTF-8. Не помогло. 
Потом вытащил готовый конфиг из EXAMPLE, заменил. Он стал выдавать:

> "500 OOPS: could not bind listening IPv4 socket"

Пробовал ставить listen YES\NO, он что-то стал писать про standalone и inetd. 
 Начал искать инфу, как перезапустить xinetd. 
Пробовал "killall -1 xinetd". Затем он начал ругаться на guest_username: virtual. 
В настройках подключения файлзиллы почему-то стоял порт 10021, (может я его поставил). Сменил на 21.
 Стал подключаться как аноним. Но мне аноним не нужен. Мне нужно разместить несколько сайтов в разных директориях и к каждому сайту отдельный ftp-доступ.
 Начал искать инфу, как добавить пользователя ftp. Что-то шаманил с addgroup ftpuser, adduser и т.д. Подключаюсь по логину\паролю созданного юзера через файлзиллу, он выдаёт, что этот сервер только анонимный. Вот получилось месиво из всех статей из инета. 
 Я уже две недели от компа не отлипаю.

Как его настроить нормально?

Answer (score 2):

На сайте vsftpd есть дерево исходников. Там лежат примеры настроек. Берется последний пример для виртуальных пользователей, сейчас это [версия 2.3.4](ftp://vsftpd.beasts.org/users/cevans/untar/vsftpd-2.3.4/EXAMPLE/VIRTUAL_USERS/README), и выполняется по шагам, которые там указаны.

Перед настрой vsftpd надо установить все необходимое:

```
sudo apt-get install vsftpd pwgen db4.7-util -y -qq
```

Генерация имени и пароля на шаге 1

```
echo name > logins.txt && pwgen -N 1 >> logins.txt
```

Вместо `db_load` выполнить `db4.7_load`:

```
db4.7_load -T -t hash -f logins.txt /etc/vsftpd_login.db
```

[Пример начальной настройки](http://igorka.com.ua/2010-03-31/primer-nachalnoj-nastrojki-vsftpd-v-ubuntu-910/) (на русском).

Comment: Это ведь, если я не ошибаюсь, пример для Ubuntu? Проблем с этим на Debian не должно быть? Просто я боюсь лишний раз ковыряться в этом putty

Comment: Да, на Debian все должно быть так же, как и на Ubuntu.